# Make an RDF file refer to other RDF files

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I have two ontologies `ontology1.owl` and `ontology2.owl` where the first depends on the second (`ontology1.owl` imports `ontology2.owl`).

I have an RDF file `instance1.rdf` that conforms to ontology1. `instance1.rdf` refers to individuals from `instance2.rdf` which conforms to `ontology2.owl`.

I have an application that employs `instance1.rdf` to do some specific logic. However, data from `instance2.rdf` are also required for the processing as `instance1.rdf` refers to individuals from `instance2.rdf`. Let's assume that all instances and ontologies are available on the web. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/ontology1.owl
http://www.example.com/ontology2.owl
http://www.example.com/instance1.rdf
http://www.example.com/instance2.rdf
```

**QUESTION**

1. The entry for my application should be `instance1.rdf` which the user should provide (or provide a link to it). However, it's not the user's responsibility to know the required `instance2.rdf`, it's rather the application responsibility and this can be known by encoding such dependency in `instance1.rdf`. Is there any elegant way to make `instance1.rdf` refer to `instance2.rdf`, so that my application knows where to retrieve instance2.rdf from and load it? The

**NOTES**

2. I do not want to use owl:import. The reason is that both files `instance1.rdf` and `instance2.rdf` are RDF files, I do not want to use owl constructs here.
3. A possible workaround is that in `instance1.rdf`, I create a special property, e.g., `dependsOn`, and set the value of the property to the link to `instance2.rdf`, and handle the rest in my application. Is this straightforward?

Comment: Why not give your application two entry points so that the user provides links to `instance1.rdf` and `instance2.rdf`? Why not just use `owl:imports`, since using OWL constructs in RDF files is perfectly legal? Why not just do the “workaround” you have outlined yourself? It looks to me like you are rejecting all sorts of perfectly fine and obvious solutions for reasons that you have not explained.

Comment: if you don't want to use `owl:import` - and honestly, I don't understand why - then no, there is no such mechanism in the RDF layer that does what you want, so yes, it's the job of your application. But, if your application does all this, why introducing a `dependsOn` property at all? This sound strange

Comment: How about using rdfs:isDefinedBy to refer to the location where elements of instance2 are defined?

Comment: Sure, you could use this property, was designed for such a reference. But in the end, your application has to handle this reference nevertheless. The difference with `owl:import` is that many applications automatically resolve the imports. But indeed, it's not a big issue to do it in your client code although I still don't get why you're not just loading all RDF files. I mean, what is the use case of parsing the RDF file, checking for references to other files and then load those files as well? I think you know all files in advance.